# Integration over inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis

What are the conditions for taking integral over an inequality?
For example given the following inequality:

$f(x)<g(x)$ when can we say $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx<\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx $$ holds?
Please give me rigorous explanation.

Comment: Riemann integrable? If so, do you know that a bounded function is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere in $[a,b]$? If so, apply this to $g-f$ and show $\int_a^b g(x)-f(x)\,dx>0$ (finding one point of continuity of $g-f$ in $[a,b]$ is all that's needed).

Answer (score 2):

This is true provided $f<g$ on a set of positive measure.

Comment: which, judging by his question, is whenever $a \neq b$